# Find strings with regex expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to search into Java packages using the following expression:

```
com.company.*
```

Test example: https://regex101.com/r/tHTQd9/2

But when I use it into Java code it's not finding anything. Do I need to put some escape characters for `.`?

Comment: The dot is a special character in regex. It means one character. You have to escape it with one backslash, if you look for the dot as single character in strings.

Comment: Having said that about escaping the dot, which is true, it won't stop it finding text for packages if it's not escaped, so you might have another problem

Comment: "it's not finding anything" unescaped dot `.` can match any character, so regex problem is that it can match too much. If it doesn't match anything then most likely your problem is in Java code.

Answer (score 2):

The following expression would work:

```
\bcom\.company\.\w[\w\.]*\b
```

- Match between word-boundaries
- Use literal dot characters by escaping
- 1 alphanumeric (or underscore) followed by 0 or more alphanumerics or dots

```java
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\bcom\\.company\\.\\w[\\w\\.]*\\b");
```

Comment: no, it's not working. Maybe the mistake is somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a word or more in the last sequence you can try:

```
com\\.company\\.\w+
```

Or, even more generic (any other character or more):

```
com\\.company\\..+
```

Please remember that this is quite generic and prone to errors.
If you provide a more detailed explanation or constraints we can help building a better RegEx.

Why double backslash in Java?

> We know that the backslash character is an escape character in Java
> String literals as well. Therefore, we need to double the backslash
> character when using it to precede any character (including the \
> character itself).

[Source](https://www.baeldung.com/java-regexp-escape-char)

Answer (score 0):

In java to escape dot (`.`) you need to append double backslash (`\\`) so your regex will be like this:

```
com\\.company\\.*
```

Why double backslash is needed:

As dot(`.`) is a special symbol in regex so you need to escape it using a backslash (`\`) but as backslash also works as an escape character in java so it will be removed by java after processing the string. In order to preserve it, we need to add another backslash (`\`)

Regex string you will see

```
 com\\.company\\.*
```

String after java processed it which will be the input as regex

```
com\.company\.*
```